# Exclude unit tests from coverage in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, coverage.py, python-coverage

I am new to using [coverage.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage). I used `coverage run unit_tests.py` which ran my tests. Then I used `coverage report` which generated the following coverage summary:

```
Name         Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------
cardnames       28      0   100%
dominion       458    210    54%
unit_tests     181      0   100%
--------------------------------
TOTAL          667    210    69%
```

Apart from including `cardnames.py` and `dominion.py` which I am trying to test inside unit_tests.py, the coverage report also includes the `unit_tests.py` file itself. (in the coverage calculation). How can I exclude this file from the report?

Comment: How is your project arranged? Are all three files in the same folder? Have you tried explicitly excluding the tests?

Comment: Yes all the 3 files are in the same folder. (All 3 are files)

Comment: You could consider restructuring the project, such that the tests are in a separate folder. This makes it easier to develop, test and distribute. See e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [documentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/source.html):

> You can further fine-tune coverage.py’s attention with the --include and --omit switches (or [run] include and [run] omit configuration values). --include is a list of filename patterns. If specified, only files matching those patterns will be measured. --omit is also a list of filename patterns, specifying files not to measure.

So, scripting from the hip, the syntax would be something like `coverage run --source=<files to be included> --omit=unit_tests.py unit_tests.py`.

Comment: Okay this sort of works. I shuffled around the args to get a working command:

coverage run --omit unit_tests.py unit_tests.py